# MySQL beginner query

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble figuring out a query. I have 2 tables, COMPANY, which contains a company id column, comp_id, and a name column. The second table, SOURCE, has a column for comp_id and a column for parts the company sells, parts.

How can I write a query to find the names of companies that produce all parts? I've figured that this uses not exist statements, but i can't figure out how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name
from company, source
where company.comp_id=source.comp_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't exactly what i'm looking for. With this query, I am receiving names of companies that do not produce all the products. I want specific companies that produce EVERY product.

Comment: I thought, source has only the companies that produce parts, otherwise you should describe your table more in details

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
SELECT c.name from company join source s on (s.comp_id = c.comp_id) where parts = [:part_id];
```

Comment: This also doesn't quite answer my question. I need specific companies that produce every single part. The SOURCE table just contains a comp_id and a part, and there could be duplicates in both columns from companies selling multiple parts, or parts being sold by multiple companies. `select distinct part from SOURCE` would give a list of the parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, count(*) AS parts_count
FROM company, source
WHERE company.comp_id = source.comp_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING parts_count = (select count(*) from source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple and command, suppose a part is "875"

```
SELECT name FROM company WHERE comp_id IN(SELECT comp_id FROM parts
WHERE parts = 875)
```

this allow you have the same part in distinct companies

Comment: I cant query with specific parts, I need companies which sell ALL parts.

Answer (score 0):

Select name from companies,source where companies.comp_id=source.comp_id;